# How can I make an entire div a link, but also have other links inside?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hotlinking

I have a div. I want it to link somewhere when you click on it, but I also want to put other links inside it, so when you click on the other links you're redirected to one place, but if you click anywhere else you're redirected somewhere else.

Here's a simple example. As it is, the "interior" link is located outside of the "exterior" link, no matter what I do.

```
<a href="#" class="exterior">
  <a href="#">interior</a>
</a>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p4ugexf4/

Comment: why do you want to put link inside link? Certainly it's not a good idea. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: @AnamulHasan Well if you click on the interior link it takes you to that link, if you click anywhere else it takes you somewhere else.

Comment: this question has no javascript tag. Did you want a javascript solution?

Comment: @Danield I know how to solve it with javascript, but I'd prefer to use html/css.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the javascript `onclick` event on the parent element of the link(s):

```css
.exterior {
  display: block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="document.location.href='https://example.com';return true;" class="exterior">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">interior</a>
</div>
```

I don't recommend to use `<a>` in `<a>` element. Using `<a>` in `<a>` isn't valid. You can check the following document on the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test link in link</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="test1">
            <a href="#" class="test2">test</a>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

You can also use two different `<a>` elements (without using javascript - only CSS solution):

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
div a.ext {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:0;
}
div a.int {
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="ext" href="https://example.com"></a>
  <a class="int" href="https://stackoverflow.com">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `return false` must be `return true`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, practical, non-javascript solution:

Break up your main link into smaller chunks - something like:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="exterior">First part of exterior link</a>
  <a href="#">interior</a> 
  <a href="#" class="exterior">Second part of exterior link etc</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.exterior {
  display: block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://bing.com" class="exterior">
  <object><a href="http://example.com">Interior</a></object>
</a>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2r7nqe6f/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning

```css
.exterior {
  display: block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}
.interior {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="bla" class="exterior">
  <a class="interior" href="blabla">Interior</a>
</a>
```

Comment: You can't have nested `a` elements. This `HTML` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".exterior a").click(function(e){
    alert('a clicked but div not triggered');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".exterior").click(function(e){
    alert("div clicked but not a");
})

<div href = "#" class="exterior">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css">interior</a>
</div>

.exterior{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
```

I used stop propagation on a element to prevent it from triggering the click on the div. And i used div as wrapper so you would have to put a windows.location if you want to redirect to an url inside the click function.

I'm not sure how you can achieve this with simply html and css. So i would suggest using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use positioning to display a link within anoter link/container.

I have created an example, it's not perfect but will give you an idea.

https://codepen.io/MartynMc/pen/gRyqXL

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="link1" href="link1.com"></a>
  <a class="link2" href="link2.com">link2</a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
}
.link1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.link2 {
  display: block;
  top: 75px;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 24pt;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```